# ASP.NET Core Token Acquisition Exception

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

While following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3) to setup a new AzureAD app, I encountered this error after finishing the 3rd page:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Jobbi3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\jakes\Desktop\Jobbi3\Jobbi3\Program.cs:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition'.
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, and I was hoping to find someone else who may have encountered it. Also, in the guide its showing how to setup a multitenant application, but I'm using a single tenant for this specific app.

Here's my startup file:

```
using Jobbi3.Util;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jobbi3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.Prompt = "select_account";
                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

                        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                            {
                                var token = await tokenAcquisition
                                    .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(Config.Scopes, user: context.Principal);
                                request.Headers.Authorization =
                                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                            })
                        );

                        var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                        .Select(u => new
                        {
                            u.DisplayName,
                            u.Mail,
                            u.UserPrincipalName,
                            u.MailboxSettings
                        })
                        .GetAsync();

                        context.Principal.AddUserGraphInfo(user);

                        try
                        {
                            var photo = await graphClient.Me
                                .Photos["48x48"]
                                .Content
                                .Request()
                                .GetAsync();

                            context.Principal.AddUserGraphPhoto(photo);
                        }
                        catch (ServiceException ex)
                        {
                            if (ex.IsMatch("ErrorItemNotFound") ||
                                ex.IsMatch("ConsumerPhotoIsNotSupported"))
                            {
                                context.Principal.AddUserGraphPhoto(null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }

                        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
                            var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Exception.Message);
                            context.Response
                                .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Authentication+error&debug={error}");
                            context.HandleResponse();

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        };

                        options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context => {
                            if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException)
                            {
                                var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Failure.Message);
                                context.Response
                                    .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Sign+in+error&debug={error}");
                                context.HandleResponse();
                            }

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        };
                    };
                })
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                }, Config.Scopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(options =>
                {
                    options.Scopes = string.Join(' ', Config.Scopes);
                });

            //services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            //    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to working with AzureAD and MS Graph, and I'm hoping someone can tell me where I've went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your documentation, I achieved the results, but I don't know why you made the mistake.
[image]

From your error message, did you ignore ***step 5***?
[image]

If you just want the completed sample,you can find it [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnet-core/tree/master/demo).
And if you just need to setup a single tenant for specific app.
1.Choose the fisrt option.
[image]
2.
[image]
Accordingly, the code here should be modified as follows.

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "{set up your own Directory (tenant) ID}",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: I'm also not sure where I made the error. I copied the Microsoft code in their repo, and it worked fine without any further changes. I must have missed something somewhere. 

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JakeStarr hi,I'm not sure if I've helped you, and if you find it helpful, you can accept it as an answer, thank you very much.